# Copy a reference formula down to stay in line with updating data

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro and one of the columns it produces is a column of dates. I wish to use this excel formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A9:A102,K2)>0, K2,J1)
```

But have it copy down so it always goes as far as the column of dates do its left. Basically when a new date gets added, this formula will copy down another cell. I tried using this:

```
Range("J2:J" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!R[7]C[-9]:R[100]C[-9],RC[1])>0, RC[1],R[-1]C)"
```

But get "method 'range' of object '_global' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works. The destination of lastrow was incorrect but this now tracks the data in the row to the left.

```
Range("J2:J" & (Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!R[7]C[-9]:R[100]C[-9],RC[1])>0, RC[1],R[-1]C)"
```